# FIWARE - How Wilma PEP Proxy deal with redirection for multiple applications?

Tags: access-control, http-redirect, fiware, multiple-sites, fiware-wilma

We are needing Wilma PEP Proxy control the access for many applications. I think it is not possible to do yet, with the latest Wilma version. Am I wrong? If I am wrong, how to deal with that?

If I am right, is there some intention to make this possible soon? Now, I am thinking of redirect the PEP response (after token validation) to another application that can do the redirecting job. What do you think about?

Comment: What do you mena by "control de access for many applications"? To protect several API ports using the same instance of Wilma PEP proxy?

Comment: If I have many sites/applications needing to control the access, I will need to have many instances of PEP proxy, one for each application, @fgalan . What about to control the access to these applications with just one PEP Proxy instance?

Comment: As Fermin said, PEP Proxy is designed to protect a single service. If you want to protect multiple service you have to deploy a PEP Proxy instance in top of each service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the comments, the PEP is planned to protect just one service. If you need to protect many services in one machine and just using one instance of Wilma, you can do as we did: after the validation of the token, Wilma redirects the request for an application that treats the flow according to the URL, thus redirecting for the right local services.